# Storage location

Tags: vmware-esx

I would like to know if it's possible to know where is located the storage.
I've got an ESX 4 where Storage1 appears (vdf command).

How can I know if this storage is local or not ?

Thank you,

Olivier

Comment: What is the output of vdf?

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible to get this kind of information with vdf.

You can use esxcfg-scsidevs to get thiss kind of information assuming you're running ESX 4.0. on ex 3.x you can try to achieve something similir with esxcfg-vmhbadevs.

First get a list of all VMFS volumes with their idenfitifer

```
# esxcfg-scsidevs -m
naa.6001e4f033e91e00116331e1341205ca:5                           /dev/sdd5            4b139c83-3c625d20-5b5f-001e4f20dcb8  0  esx-console
naa.6001e4f033e91e00116332603b989ef8:1                           /dev/sdc1            49d1c243-62458043-9894-001e4f20dcba  0  Data01
naa.6001e4f033e91e001163323f39a38e7c:1                           /dev/sdb1            49d1c271-074f9186-6cb7-001e4f20dcba  0  Backup01
naa.6001e4f033e91e001163322c38838b9c:1                           /dev/sde1            49d1c263-777126c2-8f80-001e4f20dcba  0  DC2
```

Now you can check if the VMFS Volumes are local disks or if they are SAN or iSCSI disks. I'm not sure if you see iSCSI information with the command. I'm only using local and SAN Volumes.

```
 esxcfg-scsidevs -l -d naa.6001e4f033e91e00116331e1341205ca
 naa.6001e4f033e91e00116331e1341205ca
 Device Type: Direct-Access
 Size: 12000 MB
 Display Name: Local DELL Disk (naa.6001e4f033e91e00116331e1341205ca)
 Plugin: NMP
 Console Device: /dev/sdd
 Devfs Path: /vmfs/devices/disks/naa.6001e4f033e91e00116331e1341205ca
 Vendor: DELL      Model: PERC 6/i          Revis: 1.11
 SCSI Level: 5  Is Pseudo: false Status: on
 Is RDM Capable: false Is Removable: false
 Is Local: true
 Other Names:
  vml.02000000006001e4f033e91e00116331e1341205ca504552432036
```

If you want to check VMFS volumes you can do it with a little for loop:

```
for x in `esxcfg-scsidevs -m | cut -d":" -f1`; do esxcfg-scsidevs -l -d $x; done
```